# Alignment Issues

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am new to HTML/CSS and Stack-overflow. I am working on a project for my class and I'm having problems aligning the logos, breads, condiments etc. properly. I've tried different things in CSS, but nothing seemed to work. Any help would be much appreciated. Also I apologize in advance if I am posting incorrectly, this is my first attempt at stack-overflow and I am just trying to learn!

[image: What order form is supposed to look like]

```
My attempt:
```

https://codepen.io/megmckinsey92/pen/awqVRq/?editors=1100

Comment: https://codepen.io/megmckinsey92/pen/awqVRq/?editors=1100

Comment: Welcome to SO. Post the relevant parts of your code in the question. Also add the link to codepen to your question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

For each of your `divs` that are too wide try adding this property:

```
.everythingThatIsTooWide {
  width: 25%;
  margin: auto;
 }
```

Also for each of your `divs` that that contain multiple div elements in a line such as `.extra` and `.upgrades` do this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
/* My divs */
</div>

.wrapper {
  width: 25%;
  margin: auto;
}
```